# Are JNI signatures case sensitive?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

```
unsigned char       Z
signed char jbyte   B
unsigned short      C
short               S
long                I
jlong               J
float               F
double              D
void                V
```

But can I use (iii) instead of (III)?
I know thi smight be weird question, but I ask because capital 'i' and 'd' confuse me in code.

Comment: could you give a more specific example, it's a bit hard to get what you mean

Comment: You could always have just tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and Java are case sensitive, so you have to use the same case when you use methods or identifiers in either language.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which is about the case of type specifiers in a JNI signature, not identifiers.

Comment: @EJP It's not clear to me whether the OP was talking about the signature or the native declaration of the method JNI calls, but both languages are case sensitive as is JNI.

Comment: It's entirely clear from both the table and the (III) example he asked about that he is talking about JNI method signature strings, as used for example in GetMethodID().